# How to properly share page components across MVC solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for the proper way to organize code and projects in this simple scenario in ASPNET MVC.

I have two different solutions, which are MVC Web Applications. I want them to have a common icon or other ui component which is a user avatar / login / logout form. This should be the same across both solutions.

Sharing the authentication / authorization code should be simple enough. I will just move that into a project and reference it in both solutions. But as far as the view piece - I'm not sure. Can I create a partial view in that third project and render that in both the solutions? Is that the best practice or something else?

Comment: Would [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1) work in your case? I'm not sure if I understood the issue correctly.

Comment: @Adriani6 I dont think this helps. My issue is that I don't want to have duplicate code across multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to organize a project is to create a solution and in this solution have other child projects.

Example:

1. School

   1.1 School.Web

   1.2 School.Domain

   1.3 School.CrossCutting

Within the project  "School.CrossCutting " You will put classes that can be added as a reference in any project.

Another tip is to study Domain driven Design (DDD).